# Show duplicate values within a Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Can someone help me with getting the below PowerShell code?

The $value array has some duplicate values, and I'm struggling to figure out how to get the compare operator in line 2 to work.

I want it to show me if a value is repeated anywhere within the array.
Thank you

```
foreach ($key in $value) {
    if ($key.count -gt 1) {
    Write-Host "$key" 
    }
}
```

Comment: here are some ideas that you can try, sort the array and loop over elements to find duplicates, use linq with using the distinct and finally, Set can't have duplicates so creating a set from array with duplicate will drop, https://powershell.org/2018/05/100887-2/

Comment: The details lacking in this post make it unanswerable outside of guessing. What is in $value for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Sample data**
>
> ```
> $value = "a","a","b","b","c","d","e","f","f";
> ```

**To see duplicates** and the count greater than `1` use [group-object](https://ss64.com/ps/group-object.html) and [select-object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html) to get the `Name` and `Count` properties.

```
$value | Group-Object | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1} | Select-Object Name, Count;
```

**Output**

```
Name Count
---- -----
a        2
b        2
f        2
```

---

**One way to omit duplicates** would be to use a [foreach-object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) and then pipe that over to [sort-object](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html) and use the `-unique` parameter to return only the unique values.

```
$value | ForEach-Object {$_} | Sort-Object -Unique;
```

**Another way to omit duplicates** would be to use [group-object](https://ss64.com/ps/group-object.html) along with its `-noElement` parameter and then expand the `Name` property value without a header column.

```
($value | Group-Object -NoElement).Name;
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Sort-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html)

  > `-Unique`
  >
  > Return only the unique values
- [Group-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/group-object.html)

  > ```
  > -noElement
  > ```
  >
  > Don’t include members of each group in the output objects.
- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)